# mysql bind-address=127.0.0.1 Drastically affects performance

Tags: mysql

Searching for the internet "mysql disable remote access windows" in several places I found this answer:

> [mysqld]
>
> bind-address = 127.0.0.1

But then I realized that in a mine tool inside a foreach loop where I had a lot of query to database,
something that before take 00:00:07 seconds now take 00:10:00 minutes to process

I have commented #bind-address = 127.0.0.1 and everything works as before the same process take 00:00:07 sceconds

I have added a firewall rule to block incoming and outcoming acces to mysqld.exe
So the question is:

Is that enough to avoid remote connections to local database ?

and why bind-adrress = 127.0.0.1 Drastically affects performance ?

Comment: Hard to believe: impossible actually. What else did you change? And are the clients connecting to 127.0.0.1 or `localhost`? And if the latter, is it correctly configured in your DNS/`/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I have taked a look in mi host file and I have that 127.0.0.1 localhost
::1       localhost and in phpmyadmin I have $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3306'; ... and that working good

Comment: @MTK is `--skip-networking` an option for you?

Comment: "What else did you change" ... I have configured 2 mysql servers (same config ) only port and data folder is different ( ports 3306 and 3307)

Comment: @Progman I have taked a look now in mysql manual "Do not listen for TCP/IP connections at all" ... so that seem to be a good option for my. Thank's